# Gitlab-ci cannot pass CI_COMMIT_SHA variable into my script call

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm struggling with my script (gitlab-ci.yml).

During deploy stage, I'm trying to make curl call passing into the url my CI_COMMIT_SHA variable.
Unfortunately, I'can't find a way to make it work :

```
image: node:alpine

stages:
  - deploy

deploy_preproduction:
  stage: deploy
  before_script:
    - 'apk add --update curl'

  script:
    - curl -sS -XPOST "https://myhookurl.com/webhook/deploy?env_id=xxx&secret=xxx&revision=$CI_COMMIT_SHA"

  environment:
    name: preproduction
    url: https://myebsite.com
  only:
  - master
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Test it with something very verbose first, like:

```
curl -v "https://google.com/?q=$CI_COMMIT_SHA
```

And verify the variable is indeed injected. Then change it to your setup.

Also; How do you tell it is not working?

Comment: You're right, I've just realized that my call is correct ! This is an issue with the website where I realize curl calls ! Thanks for your help !